# published asp.net web app and published wcf service not connectiing in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, publish

I have published both my WCF service and ASP.NET Web application in IIS but i seem to have a problem connecting to the database after  publishing. Its like the two cannot see each other. I have tested both and saw that they have been successfully published.

the service reference is referenced in the web application and works as normal when i run the web application locally but not working after publishing.

Is there a setting that i am missing. Both are hosted on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that you are using 
Windows authentication, I mean if Integrated Security = true in your connection string than make sure your Windows authentication enabled in your IIS.

Do this if this is the case.
[IIS7: Setup Integrated Windows Authentication like in IIS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436169/iis7-setup-integrated-windows-authentication-like-in-iis6)

if this is not the case than this answer is helpful for you
[Change connection string from development to production when publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389101/change-connection-string-from-development-to-production-when-publishing)

Comment: The database connection is good everything is done accordingly. The problem is when i need to connect to the service. They are not connecting or rather not seeing each other so that the connection can be established and i can use the WCF services that are used to communicate with the database.